# NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE - Possible null pointer dereferenc <package>matchesSafely(View) due to return value of called method

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I have this method to get child count from a recycler view, but it is throwing spotbug error

> A failure occurred while executing com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForHybrid$SpotBugsExecutor
> Verification failed: SpotBugs ended with exit code 3See the report at:
> NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE - Possible null pointer dereferenc ...matchesSafely(View) due to return value of called method

```
public static int getCountFromRecyclerView(@IdRes int RecyclerViewId) {
    final int[] COUNT = {
        0
    };
    Matcher matcher = new TypeSafeMatcher < View > () {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
            COUNT[0] = ((RecyclerView) item).getAdapter().getItemCount();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {}
    };
    onView(allOf(withId(RecyclerViewId), isDisplayed())).check(matches(matcher));
    return COUNT[0];
}
```

Tried adding `Objects.requireNonNull` and   `@SuppressFBWarnings("NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE")`. Nothing seems to work.

This block is the reason for the error

```
protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
    COUNT[0] = ((RecyclerView) item).getAdapter().getItemCount();
    return true;
```

Comment: This modification fixed the issue.

`protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) item;
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        RecyclerView.Adapter << ? > adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null) {
            COUNT[0] = adapter.getItemCount();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}`